# Trouble using Spring Config Server in jhipster-registry

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud-config

I created a microservice architecture using JHipster. I am using the jhipster-registry v2.8.0. I renamed the 'dev' profile to 'devdmi' because I will have many 'dev' profiles. It is working OK using the "dev,native" profiles for the jhipster-registry and each microservice including it's application-devdmi.yml / boostrap-devdmi.yml files.

I tried to convert this configuration over to using a Git repo. I built my Git repo with .yml files, but I'm not exactly sure of the configuration to use. At the moment I've got:

```
MyConfig/app1/MyApp1-devdmi.yml
MyConfig/app2/MyApp2-devdmi.yml
```

I also tried using:

```
MyConfig/MyApp1-devdmi.yml
MyConfig/MyApp2-devdmi.yml
```

In MyApp1, I renamed src/main/resources/config/application-devdmi.yml to application-devdmi.yml.bak hoping it would pick up the config from the jhipster-registry acting as a Spring Cloud Config Server.

In MyApp1, I have a bootstrap-devdmi.yml with:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: my-app-1
    cloud:
        config:
            fail-fast: true
            uri: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@my.host.com:8761/config
            name: MyApp1
            profile: devdmi 
            label: master
```

The jhipster-registry starts up and shows it is connected to the Git repo by looking at the Configuration webpage.

MyApps1 doesn't start and throws an error about Liquibase not knowing which database to connect to:

```
2017-05-23 13:09:52.669  WARN 60704 --- [           main]         o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error    creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class   path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation    /web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor  before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating  bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'  defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate    [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException)
2017-05-23 13:09:52.683 ERROR 60704 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
```

Any ideas?

Comment: MyConfig/MyApp1-devdmi.yml is the right way, have you checked that the registry config endpoint returns your config in a browser? You have a bootstrap-devdmi.yml, why not simply bootstrap.yml?

Comment: http://my.host.com:8761/config/MyApps1/devjsf/master works

JHipster generates a bootstrap.yml and a bootstrap-devdmi.yml. It looks like the jhipster.registry.password is correct in bootstrap-devdmi.yml and incorrect in bootstrap.yml. Does bootstrap-devdmi.yml override bootstrap.yml?

Comment: bootstrap*.yml files work the same way as application*.yml files. So yes they are combined and if bootstrap-devdmi.yml contains same keys as bootstrap.yml, the values from bootstrap-devdmi.yml are taken. Are you sure that spring.profiles.active is equal to devdmi? Do you see it in log?

Comment: By the way, that's a strange name for a profile, why not setting 2 profiles: dev and another one with `--spring.profiles.active=dev,dmi` ? This way you would be compatible with profiles generated by JHipster. Have you checked that your yml files do not contain spring.profiles.active property?

Comment: Good point about the profile naming. I might need to try that to activate 2 profiles. I do have spring.profiles.active being set on the command-line with -Dsprint.profiles.active, and in the bootstrap-devdmi.yml (not in bootstrap.yml). I'm setting this to devdmi, but not sure if that confuses Spring and it really has to be "dev" or "prod"